# Text-only FULL News Reader / Aggregator app or service

Tags: rss, reading

I'm looking for a news reader / aggregator app or service that:

- Presents FULL articles without having to visit another website
- Presents both article "list" and "content" views as TEXT ONLY (no article images)

On one of the following platforms:

- iPhone app
- Email "newsletter"-style service

Optional / Preferred:

- Ad-free option (e.g., paid app or subscription service)
- Free option or trial (for trying out the app before purchasing ad-free)
- Search-based, tags-based, or interest category filtering / customization -- to limit to articles/content that's relevant to me